# Python if/else explanation

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to make a Discord bot for my Server and I need help by finding out if the Person is an Mod or not.

**Here's the Code:**

```
@client.hybrid_command(description="All Commands")
async def cmds(ctx):
if has_role('HCRP | Staff Team'):
print("Is Staff")

else:
print("Is Member")
```

I want it to tell me what Role the Person has but it says always is Staff.

Comment: That code will generate an `IndentationError`. Please fix it. It's not reasonable to expect us to guess at which errors are typos and which are significant.

Comment: Is this the actual indentation of you current code? Python places significance on the level of indentation.

Comment: I want him to print something If he has the Role Staff Team. If he doesnt it should run the other Code

Comment: how does `has_role` function know anything about the current user?

Comment: It tells if the author of the message has the Specific role

Comment: @lucas, please don't make semantic changes code snippets on your own. OP is the only one who knows what their code _actually_ looks like.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the comment. I do not normally do, but this was looking so clear. But you are wright the OP is the one that should made the changes.

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte, I agree that in this case your edit was probably correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@client.hybrid_command(description="all commands")
async def cmds(ctx:commands.Context):
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
    if role in ctx.author.roles:
        print("Is Staff")
    else:
        print("Is Member")
```

In this code we define the `guild` which is the server the command was executed on. Then use the `guild.get_role()` function to define the role by it's id. Then we check if that role is the `ctx.author's` roles.

Answer (score 0):

In Discord.py, you can't directly check for a role using the has_role('Role Name') function like you've tried in the code snippet. You need to check the roles of the member who invoked the command and then see if they have the desired role.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to correctly check if a member has a specific role:

```
@client.command()
async def cmds(ctx):

    member = ctx.author[![enter image description here][1]][1]

    if any(role.name == 'HCRP | Staff Team' for role in member.roles):
        print("Is Staff")
    else:
        print("Is Member")
```